# Does it make sense to test significance levels of correlation matrix obtained with glm

Tags: correlation, generalized-linear-model

I am using a logistic regression and always like to have a look at the coefficient correlation. For example, here is a code where I am looking at a simple logistic regression between an outcome variable (x, dichotomous) and a few predictor variables (continuous and ordinal: a, b, c, d, e).

```
a <- rnorm(100)
b <- rnorm(100)
c <- sample(rep(c(1,2,3,4),times=100))
d <- sample(rep(c(1,2),times=100))
e <- sample(rep(c(0,1,2,3),times=100))
x <- sample(rep(c("case","control"),times=100))

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,x)
df$x <- factor(df$x)

glmModel = glm(I(x == "case") ~ ., family = binomial(), data = df)
corrMat = summary(glmModel, corr=TRUE)$correlation
```

|  | (Intercept) | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 1.00000000 | -0.05807459 | -0.03594247 | -0.54462425 | -0.74059196 | -0.33549389 |
| a | -0.05807459 | 1.00000000 | -0.17826515 | 0.02423815 | -0.01155441 | 0.01789369 |
| b | -0.03594247 | -0.17826515 | 1.00000000 | -0.04101731 | 0.10723187 | -0.03763901 |
| c | -0.54462425 | 0.02423815 | -0.04101731 | 1.00000000 | 0.01218383 | -0.01340827 |
| d | -0.74059196 | -0.01155441 | 0.10723187 | 0.01218383 | 1.00000000 | 0.02651398 |
| e | -0.33549389 | 0.01789369 | -0.03763901 | -0.01340827 | 0.02651398 | 1.00000000 |

Would it make sense to test this matrix for significance between those correlation coefficients?

Comment: You tell us: what question of any scientific or statistical value would you be answering with such a test?  Indeed, what exactly do you mean by "significance"?  What null hypothesis are you contemplating?

Comment: My goal is to see whether there's a correlation between the predictors. For example, if these were continuous variable with a normal distribution, I could do a pearson correlation and calculate a pvalue from the coefficient matrix. The results would tell me whether the variables are correlated.

Comment: Now here it's a lot different, I can do the glm to see whether there is a relationship between predictors and the dichotomous variable, but the correlation here links the estimated coefficients.  I just don't know how to use it.

Comment: The covariance matrix of the *estimates* is, at best, an indirect way to assess the correlation of the *explanatory variables* because it depends on the model and how it is fit.  If you want to study the relationships among the predictors, do so directly.